# CSS Compression does not display @font-face

Tags: css, compression, font-face, webfonts

So everything is fine with the following until I compress the css.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'modern_pictogramsnormal';
src: url('modernpics-webfont.eot');
src: url('modernpics-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('modernpics-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('modernpics-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('modernpics-webfont.svg#modern_pictogramsnormal') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Am I missing a something? Do I need to do something with Apache or the htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute Url fixed the compression issue